# Java : my program "sometimes" wont store the smallest element per row of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, 2d, long-integer

Ok so I have a 2d array of objects which have a long value and I'm trying to find the smallest long in each row and save it into an array and then subtract the smallest value per row from all other values in that row but for some reason when I run it, it sometimes just saves a "0" as the rows smallest value when there's no zero in the row? it's really odd and I need some help

Here's the code:

```
public void doAlgorithm(){
    generateMatrix(initialMatrix);

    printMatrix(initialMatrix); //
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    reducedMatrix1 = initialMatrix;
    reduceBySmallestRow();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    printMatrix(reducedMatrix1);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

}
/**
 * Fills matrix with random values between 1 and 1000
 */
public void generateMatrix(MatrixObject[][] initialMatrix){
    long LOWER_RANGE = 1; 
    long UPPER_RANGE = 1000; 
    //Random random = new Random();

    for(int i=0 ; i<matrixLength ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<matrixLength ; j++){
            MatrixObject obj1 = new MatrixObject(); 
            Random random = new Random();
            long randomValue = LOWER_RANGE + 
                    (long)(random.nextDouble()*(UPPER_RANGE - LOWER_RANGE));
            obj1.setObjectValue(randomValue);
            obj1.setMarkRow(false);
            obj1.setMarkCol(false);
            this.initialMatrix[i][j] = obj1;
        }
    }
    //initialMatrix = this.initialMatrix;

}

public void reduceBySmallestRow(){
        long[] rowHolder =new long[matrixLength];
        // searches each row in matrix to find smallest number per row.
        long z;
        for(int i=0 ; i<matrixLength ; i++){
            z = reducedMatrix1[i][0].getObjectValue();
            for(int j=0 ; j<matrixLength ; j++){
                if(reducedMatrix1[i][j].getObjectValue() < z){
                    z = reducedMatrix1[i][j].getObjectValue();
                    rowHolder[i]=z;
                    }
                }

        }

        for(int i=0 ; i<matrixLength ; i++){
            long newVal;
            //System.out.print(rowHolder[i]+"  ");
            for(int j=0 ; j<matrixLength ; j++){
                //System.out.println(rowHolder[i]);
                newVal = reducedMatrix1[i][j].getObjectValue() - rowHolder[i];
                reducedMatrix1[i][j].setObjectValue(newVal);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output for test case 1:

841   836   107   116    92

756   289   634   905   839

179   244   988   355   457

579   202   499   475   889

698   648   578    28   557

92
289
0
202
28

749   744    15    24     0

467     0   345   616   550

179   244   988   355   457

377     0   297   273   687

670   620   550     0   529

output for test case 2:
 683   602   987   169   297

408   915   994   139   715

93   476   171   934    78

687   877    51   735   531

139   970   126   627   454

169
139
78
51
126

514   433   818     0   128

269   776   855     0   576

15   398    93   856     0

636   826     0   684   480

13   844     0   501   328

output for test case 3:
 823   782   939   690   209

693   740   995    73   313

258   610   424   249    11

771   692   889   657    97

51   834   811   238   454

209
73
11
97
0

614   573   730   481     0

620   667   922     0   240

247   599   413   238     0

674   595   792   560     0

51   834   811   238   454

Comment: Please Read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

For finding minum number your loop should be like this

```
 for(int i=0 ; i<matrixLength ; i++){
       z = reducedMatrix1[i][0].getObjectValue();
       rowHolder[i]=z; //added this line
       for(int j=0 ; j<matrixLength ; j++){
           if(reducedMatrix1[i][j].getObjectValue() < z){
                 z = reducedMatrix1[i][j].getObjectValue();
                 rowHolder[i]=z;
            }
        }
  }
```

you were getting a zero because 179 (test case 1)was the **first and smallest** number and due to which inside the for-loop `rowHolder` wasnt getting updated at all.

Comment: @Ifc4prem accept the answer, if it helped you, click on the tick appearing to left of answer